# Conda is installing a very old version of pytorch-lightning

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, conda, pytorch-lightning

I tried installing pytorch lightning by runnning:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pytorch-lightning
```

as described here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytorch-lightning
This link seems updated to version 1.6.5

However, when I run this command, an old version of pytorch-lightning is installed, as can be seen here:

> ```
> > The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
> > 
> >   absl-py            pkgs/main/noarch::absl-py-0.15.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0  
> > blinker            pkgs/main/linux-64::blinker-1.4-py39h06a4308_0  
> > google-auth-oauth~ pkgs/main/noarch::google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1-py_2  
> > oauthlib           pkgs/main/noarch::oauthlib-3.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0  
> > pytorch-lightning  conda-forge/noarch::pytorch-lightning-0.8.5-py_0  
> > requests-oauthlib  pkgs/main/noarch::requests-oauthlib-1.3.0-py_0  
> > tensorboard        pkgs/main/noarch::tensorboard-2.6.0-py_1  
> > tensorboard-data-~
> > pkgs/main/linux-64::tensorboard-data-server-0.6.0-py39hca6d32c_0  
> > tensorboard-plugi~ pkgs/main/noarch::tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.6.0-py_0
> ```

As you can see, version 0.8.5 is being installed. Is there a way for me to use conda and get a newer version of pytorch-lightning?

Things I have tried:

1. updating conda
2. using both linux and windows

Comment: start with a fresh environment. you might on an old version of python or have another package that is constraining dependencies

Comment: @PaulH thanks for the suggestion. I am running this on a new linux machine where the OS was installed only 4 weeks ago so I think everything should be reasonably up to date, although I will double check. I wonder if my problem is reproducable for other people also.

Comment: @PaulH turns out you were right! Thank you.  Ill post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by launching a new conda environment. Apparently there were some conflicting pre installed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, when I launched a new conda environment with Python v3.7, it would *still* install an old version of PyTorch Lightning.
Moving up the conda env to Python v3.9 solved it for me.